Generating only one index.js in vite rollup
Is there a way of telling vite rollup to just generate one index.js bundle asset? I am trying to use the rollup configuration in vite but it produces the main index.js asset and a few other index.js chunks.
This is my configuration:
export default defineConfig(({}) => {
  return {
    plugins: [react(), nodePolyfills()],
    build: {
      outDir: resolve(__dirname, `dist/`),
      rollupOptions: {
        input: resolve(__dirname, `src/index.ts`),
        output: {
          entryFileNames: '[name].js',
          manualChunks: undefined,
        },
      }
    }
  };
});

